# Class in Singleton style but it receives parameters (information) before instance is created

Tags: java, javafx, singleton

Here is what I'm doing:

I have a little GUI program (JavaFX) that contains a login and a main page. The main page is set up with a `BorderPane`. The center of the BoraderPane is filled with different sub-scenes. This depends on which content the user wants to see.

Now, some sub-scenes execute tasks which require information about the user. **Hence, I need to share my user among different controllers.**

I did some [research](https://dev.to/devtony101/javafx-3-ways-of-passing-information-between-scenes-1bm8) and I think I found a fitting solution: Create a User-Class which implements the singleton pattern.

This is where I get stuck. Since the user is unknown I can't create the User-Class in advance. First the user has to sign-up and then I can create the Singleton.

The referred link has a `UserHolder` class which then holds a `User` object.

**Question:**

1 Is it possible to create a Singleton that gets injected with information (parameters) before its instance is created?

2 If this is possible, how would this be done?

Comment: If my memory serves me correctly, the singleton style does not work well with JavaFX. Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx

Comment: Singleton is a horrible anti-pattern. Just pass the information you need between different controllers, or use a dependency injection framework.

Comment: @James_D I've read the prhase "Singleton is a horrible anti-pattern" quite a lot know and I'm starting to doubt if it is even of any good. Can you clarify or lead me to some sources where this topic is discussed? I know the benefit of its design and am unclear about its drawbacks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons